# QT C++ - Open Network Drive

Tags: c++, qt

I have a UI where there are two buttons:

1. Set directory - provides a navigation dialog for user to select a directory
2. Open directory - opens window to set directory

My code below would work for a local directory, but does not work on a networked directory. When I set the directory as the network path `//my.network.path.com/jon/` and try to open the directory, window directory does not appear and QT output logs `ShellExecute '//my.network.path.com/jon' failed (error 2).` Does QT not have access to Network drives?

```
QDir mSaveDirectory;    
void setDirectory()
{
    QWidget *widget;
    QString directoryPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(widget, "Select Directory", "/", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
    mSaveDirectory.setPath(directoryPath);
}
void openDirectory() const
{
    QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("file");
    url.setPath(mSaveDirectory.absolutePath());
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Does the environment you're executing from have sufficient privs to access the drive? You might need to start Qt Creator as Admin, or some user that has the credentials to access it correctly.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory According to Qt Documentation, "_The main difference with_ `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory()` _comes from the ability offered to the user to select a remote directory_.  _That's why the return type and the type of dir is_ `QUrl`... _This function was introduced in Qt_ _5.2_  " So it seems you're doing that correctly.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I am using Visual Studio as admin. In addition, I am able to access that network drive.

Comment: Maybe it's how the URL is being used? For example, from Ubuntu doc's, a Windows fileshare would typically be accessed with `smb://domain-name/fileshare`; perhaps Qt expects the same? It could be a total red-herring. If Qt is using sh-style connections under the hood, it could help to reference something like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html

Comment: OS and Qt Version?

Comment: @deW1 Win7, QT 5.6

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I tried using `smb` but that did not work

Comment: Since you are on windows, shouldn't the path be made from backslashes? \\my.network.path.com\jon\

Comment: @Bowdzone Yes, but `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(widget, "Select Directory", "/", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly)` returns the path with forward slashes